# What is the advantage of POSIX queue or just normal data structure queue?

Tags: c, data-structures, linux, message-queue, posix

I'm programming with the embedded device running Linux, where memory is less, I just have 64MB flash only. I planned to use queues for the thread communication.

In which I came across with using POSIX queue or just use the simple queue.

Actually, my need is I don't want the queue to be priority driven. I want to know the pros and cons of POSIX queue then I'll have a good picture

I'm wondering what's the best-optimised way using `POSIX` queue or just simple queue to my situation?

First thread does `HTTP POST` and Second thread does `HTTP GET`. These two threads need to communicate when the data is written or get.

I read that POSIX queue uses Linux kernel, in that case, it has more overhead than using own data structure queue?

In other words, lightweight IPC, something like unidirectional pipes for thread communication instead of POSIX queue but don't know the real advantage of POSIX queue.

EDIT: I just have 512MB RAM in my embedded device.

Answer (score 3):

A POSIX queue (see [mq_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html)) is for inter-process communication (so is quite expensive, but it could be used for inter-thread communication). You could use a queue data structure protected by e.g. a POSIX mutex. Hopefully (thanks to [futex(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/futex.7.html) probably used by [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html)) you won't need a context switch to the kernel in the common cases where no locking is needed.

> I'm programming with the embedded device running Linux, where memory is less, I just have 64MB flash only.

AFAIK the flash device is more a disk -i.e. a block device- than a memory. POSIX queues or pipes will consume RAM (actually virtual address space and kernel memory space), not flash.

If you already have some event loop (e.g. around [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) or the old [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) ...) you could set up a [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) to self at initialization time (and have one thread writing the pipe, and another reading it).

> First thread does HTTP POST and Second thread does HTTP GET.

Did you consider using some [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) client library like [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) (perhaps using its [multi](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html) mode)? It could be helpful (and you could avoid multi-threading if you think in [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style)).

> I'm wondering what's the best-optimised way using POSIX queue or just simple queue to my situation?

For [synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)) purposes (in a multi-threading approach) the "simple queue" needs e.g. some mutex (to lock & serialize access hence avoiding both threads modifying it simultaneously; the kernel is still involved thru futexes on contention). I don't know what is faster (I am not sure it is important but I would prefer mutexes & multi-threading), and **you need to benchmark** if you really care.

BTW, multi-threading (and also multi-processing) is consuming memory (since each thread probably wants at least one megabyte for its [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)).

Comment: How about using UNIX unidirectional pipes as IPC, is it a bad idea to do that?

Comment: No, it is a good idea, and more compatible with most event loops (e.g. using [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html))

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, yes, I'm using libcurl. I have dispatcher which runs select() which is similar to poll().